# How to position multiple div's

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to make a simple web-application, but I am having some troubles with the positioning of my div's

I tried to make it so I have `1 large bar` on the `top` with a `100% width`, `1 large bar` at the `bottom` with a `100% width` and a navigation menu on the side that is stuck to the left and fits exactly between the other two bars. I also want it to stay where it is when I scroll down.

The code I used for the navigation menu is

```
{background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    width: 15%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-top: 7%;
    margin-bottom: 3%
}
```

for the top bar

```
{background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 93%;
}
```

and for the footer

```
{background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3%;
    margin-top: 97%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

the div's are al placed in the body like this

```
<body><div id="top"></div><div id="menu"></div><div id="footer"></div></body>
```

the menu is placed fine this way but the header and footer are stuck to the top of the page.

Thank you anyone who can help me out

Comment: Need to see your code, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With position:fixed you'll need to specify the top/bottom and left styles.  I don't think you'll need those margin styles.

```
#menu {
    background-color: blue;
    position: fixed;
    width: 15%;
    height: 90%;
    top: 7%;
    left: 0;
}
#top {
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#footer {
    background-color: green;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```